# update on multitable relation

Tags: php, mysql

I have **three tables users_tbl, skill_tbl, user_skill_tbl** where

```
users_tbl have 1 to many relations with user_skill_tbl(auto increment) 
and skill_tbl have 1 to many relations with the user_skill_tbl.
user_skill_tbl have user_skill_id, skill_id and user_id.
```

I don't have a problem in inserting the data in the tables.

I have a form where users detail and multiple check option of skill(i get the skill_id only) is there.

when the from is filled, first the user's table is inserted then the last inserted id is taken and the user_skill_tbl is inserted. 
But My problem is when I have to update the user_skill_tbl I have used

```
$skill = $_POST['skill_id'];
for($i=0;$i < count($skill); i++){

 $name[$i]= mysqli_escpae_string($con,$skill[$i]);

 $query = "update into user_skill_tbl (skill_id) 

 values ('$skill_id') where user_id = '$user_id'"
```

after the query is executed the last id of the skill_id is updated on all the skill_id in the user_skill_tbl. I know that I should manipulate along with the user_skill_id but I am not being able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are mixing up the update and insert syntax with "update into". It's "update tablename" or "insert into tablename".

I am not sure how you store your data in `user_skill_tbl` but if, as I guess, for each user you only store the records related to his/her skills, you need to first delete all the skills for the current user, something like:

```
$query = "delete from user_skill_tbl where user_id = '$user_id'"
```

and then add each skill in your for loop:

```
$query = "insert into user_skill_tbl (skill_id, user_id) values
 ('$skill_id', '$user_id')
```

Put everything in a transaction to avoid inconsistencies if something goes wrong during the execution.

Comment: Thank you. I got confused but then the problem is solved